# Repeating “Unfortunately Google App has stopped” error on Nexus 5

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, nexus-5, crashes

My Nexus 5 stated acting strange in the past few days.

Here's the short history:

- A few days ago, I was prompted to install a new version in OTA update. Done.
- Yesterday, phone shut off just like that by itself. When powered on, it has a message on a black screen saying "optimizing app x/150". When it was done, phone booted.
- This morning: wanted to access Google Now, but it wasn't there - I couldn't flick to the left. Was prompted to 'reactivate' google Now, which I did. I should mention it was there after the OTA update.

Since then, every few seconds, and pretty much whatever I try to do, the error message in the title pops up. (side note: strangely, it says Google App and not Apps). Extremely hard to use the phone when every few seconds this pops up. Help, anyone? Thanks!

Comment: Try clearing cache for those apps in *Settings › Apps*. If the permanent pop-ups don't let you do that, try the same from [safe-mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This thing is, I don't know which app to clear the cache to. It just says the generic "Google App". I tried clearing the cache via Android Assistant, but the problem persists.

Comment: I'd say the "Google App" is the app named "Google" (no kidding: there's such one in my app drawer – but I indeed cannot find it in *Settings › Apps*). Just tried the one from the drawer, brings me to *Google Now*. Going by the icon, the corresponding app in *Settings* must be *Google Search* – which makes sense considering *Google Now* is part of that. // Using "small atomics": You can clear all app caches at once by booting into recovery and "wipe cache". No data lost that way.

Comment: Update: I deactivates Now and Cards from Google Settings (not the general settings, which is probably something that confused me), and this problem was resolved (at the price of losing Now).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Optimesh! As this at least solved the issue, I made it an answer. I also included some additional details, so maybe you can bring back that "lost functionality" if you need it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As it says "Google App", it's most likely the app named [Google](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox) (no kidding: there's such one, just follow the link – though I cannot find it in *Settings › Apps* by that name). Just tried the one from the drawer, brings me to *Google Now* – which again matches the app you've got trouble with, as your question states: "wanted to access Google Now, but it wasn't there".

Going by the icon, the corresponding app in *Settings* must be *Google Search* – which again makes sense considering *Google Now* is part of that.

So I'd suggest you try to go there (in *Settings › Apps*) and clear it's cache. If that doesn't help, try clearing its data as well (same place). If that doesn't solve it, open the *Google Settings* app (not the general device settings, but the settings app with the "g" for "Google" in its icon – you can find it in the app drawer) and deactivate *Now and Cards* there. This disables *Google Now*, but solves the issue (as you've proven).

Hint in case you cannot reach out to *Settings* or the *Google Settings* app (e.g. if that pop-up reappears faster than you can tap somewhere else): You can clear all app caches at once by booting to [recovery-mode](/questions/tagged/recovery-mode) and "wipe cache". No data lost that way. Another good hint in this context is [safe-mode](/questions/tagged/safe-mode): if the troublemaker is a user-app, it won't be started here, so you can clear cache/delete data/deactivate/uninstall such an app from there.

Comment: Just to clarify, the Now app appears under "Google Settings" and not the general settings app.

Comment: That might be, but Now is part of Search AFAIK. Btw: As this solved your issue, consider ticking the check-mark next to the answer to indicate such – which then helps others with this problem identifying working solutions :)

Comment: Yea I want to do so but I feel the information needs to be complete. I've spent a lot of time looking for the app at the wrong place. It can get confusing between Settings and Google Settings. The latter is where the solution lies. I feel like the answer should reflect that.

Comment: So what do you miss in there that I should add? It's already more complete than the hints I gave in the comments which lead to your solving the issue :) That the Now app appears in *Google Settings* is not related to your issue as far as I see it. Lots of Google stuff appears in their settings app, logically :) – Oh, reading the comments again (reflecting your latest now) it seems I slightly misunderstood you. Please check back in 2 minutes, I'll update my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The solutions posted so far failed to fix the problem for me, so I looked at the system log (`adb logcat`) and saw this error immediately after seeing the popup message:

```
F/libc (23416): Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL) at 0x5d7ca8f4 (code=1), thread 23528 (HotwordDetector)
```

I finally resolved the problem in Google Settings → Search & Now → Voice → "Ok Google" detection, where I disabled "From the Google app."

You may see a different "logcat" error than the above, but hopefully your specific error message will lead you closer to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the app store and uninstall the updates. Then open the app without updating. Fixed mine.